# Firebase how to delete an image from storage upon disconnect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I'm trying to delete an uploaded image when the connection has been disconnected.

In the below code, I'm attempting to delete the image from the storage during disconnect. However, the "storageRef.delete();" is occurring even though connection is still active.

```js
    var connectedRef = database.ref(".info/connected");
    var connectionsImgRef = database.ref("/imageConnections");
    
    var imgCon = "";
    connectedRef.on("value", function (snap) {
        if (snap.val()) {
            $("#submitImage").on("click", function () {
                event.preventDefault();

                var fileName = selectedFile.name;
                storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("images/" + fileName);
                
                var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);
                uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
                    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                    switch (snapshot.state) {
                        case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                            console.log('Upload is paused');
                            break;
                        case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                            console.log('Upload is running');
                            break;
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                
                }, function () {
               uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
                        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);

                        userImgURL = downloadURL;

                        imgCon = connectionsImgRef.push(userImgURL);

                        userDisplayImg.attr("src", downloadURL);
                        userDisplayImg.addClass("userImage")
                        $("#uploadedImg").html(userDisplayImg);

                        //Issue: the remove is initiated even before disconnect.
                        imgCon.onDisconnect().remove(() => {
                            console.log("call back initiated")
                            storageRef.delete();
                        });
                        
                        //Issue: the remove is initiated even before disconnect.
                        // imgCon.onDisconnect().remove(function () {
                        //     storageRef.delete();
                        // });
                    })

                });
            });
        };
    });
```

```html
<!-- Note this is using bootstrap's classes. -->

<input type="file" class="custom-file-input upload-group" id="file">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Upload an image!</label>

<button id="submitImage" class="btn btn-light">Upload</button>
```